# bash: pip: command not found mac os high sierra

Tags: python, macos, pip

I can't use pip. I've tried reinstalling pip.

iterm returned:

```
already installed here: Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

So I added `Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg` to my path:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ export PATH=$PATH:Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ which pip
MacBook-Pro:~ user$
```

It doesn't seem to be working, even though i tried installing `pip` in `/usr/bin`

Comment: How you install `pip`? `sudo easy_install pip`?

Comment: it is already installed, and i tried with easy_install pip. I resolved this issue by exporting to a different path: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```